# autologoutlink="true" causes login button increase in width in Firefox 14

Tags: facebook, button, authentication, xfbml, facebook-fbml

Recently (not sure when) the fb:login-button on my site has started to slowly increase in width in Firefox. I can stop this happening by setting autologoutlink="false", but I would like to keep it set to true. You can see this on the following site as the "Backup" button creeps across the page, left to right.

http://grepbook.co.uk/

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11452948/facebook-logout-button-creeps-across-the-screen-in-firefox

Comment: Bug on fb: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/302726826490772 Seems to be fixed now.